# nas linhas 45 e 47 esse erro aparece: error CS0029: Cannot implicitly convert type 'UnityEngine.GameObject' to 'UnityEngine.Transform'

Tags: c#, unity3d

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerMovement : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float Speed;
    public float JumpForce;

    public bool isJump;
    public bool isDoubleJump;

    private Animator anim;
    private Rigidbody2D rig;

    public GameObject projetilPrefab;
    public float velocidadeProjetil;
    public GameObject Tiro;
    public GameObject Tiro2;

    private bool facingRight = true;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        rig = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
        anim = GetComponent<Animator>();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        Move();
        Jump();
    }

    void Atirar()
    {
        if(Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
        {
            Transform shotPoint;

            if(Mathf.Abs(rig.velocity.x) > 0)
                shotPoint = Tiro;
            else
                shotPoint = Tiro2;

            GameObject projectile = Instantiate(projetilPrefab, shotPoint.position, transform.rotation);

            if(facingRight)
                projectile.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity = new Vector2(velocidadeProjetil, 0);
            else
                projectile.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity = new Vector2(-velocidadeProjetil, 0);                
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

ShotPoint é um Transform e vc ta atribuindo Tiro pra ele, e tiro é um GameObject, por isso o problema.

Troca:

```
if(Mathf.Abs(rig.velocity.x) > 0)
        shotPoint = Tiro;
    else
        shotPoint = Tiro2;
```

Por isso:

```
if(Mathf.Abs(rig.velocity.x) > 0)
        shotPoint = Tiro.transform;
    else
        shotPoint = Tiro2.transform;
```

N

Comment: Muito obrigado. Vou testar, se houver mais alguma dúvida eu retorno.